When submitting form, I get "Cannot Post /"
I am building a reverse proxy, in it, there is a form box. It is supposed to get user input, and check if it is:

a url;
a url without the https:// header, which it adds;
or plain text, which is routed into a search engine.

Wen submitting the form, no matter what is in it, it returns "Cannot Post /" in a blank page. My index.html form is this.
<div class="search-container">
    <p>Join the <a href="https://discord.gg/3TTahctF">discord</a>!</p>
    <form id="fs" method="POST">
        <input id="is" class="main-search" placeholder="A World, Uncensored" type="text" />
    </form>
</div>

In my index.js, which is connected, this.
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('../sw.js?v=4', {
    scope: '/a/',
  })
})

const form = document.getElementById('fs')
const input = document.getElementById('is')

if (form && input) {
  form.addEventListener("submit", async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    processUrl(input.value, "");
  });
}

function processUrl(value, path) {
  let url = value.trim()
  const engine = localStorage.getItem('engine')
  const searchUrl = engine ? engine : 'https://www.google.com/search?q='

  if (!isUrl(url)) {
    url = searchUrl + url
  } else if (!(url.startsWith('https://') || url.startsWith('http://'))) {
    url = 'https://' + url
  }

  sessionStorage.setItem('GoUrl', __uv$config.encodeUrl(url))
  const dy = localStorage.getItem('dy')

  if (path) {
    location.href = path
  } else if (dy === 'true') {
    window.location.href = '/a/q/' + __uv$config.encodeUrl(url)
  } else {
    window.location.href = '/a/' + __uv$config.encodeUrl(url)
  }
}

function isUrl(val = '') {
  if (/^http(s?):\/\//.test(val) || (val.includes('.') && val.substr(0, 1) !== ' ')) return true
  return false
}

First, I tried changing the form's method, which gave me a similar error. Then, after doing research online, I came to this link. Although similar, it is focused on an express error, while mine is basic javascript (client side).

Why does your form not POST, but rewrite the current browser URL instead?
